# Google Play requests access to Photos/Media/Files

Tags: android

I have uploaded a new version to Google Play.
The update require accepting new permission Photos/Media/Files that wasn't mentioned in the application merged manifest.

The require permissions from Google Play Console:

```
Required permissions 13 permissions 
android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION 
android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE 
android.permission.CAMERA
android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS
android.permission.INTERNET
android.permission.READ_CONTACTS
android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
android.permission.READ_PROFILE
android.permission.VIBRATE
android.permission.WAKE_LOCK
android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE maxSdkVersion=18
com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE
com.****.permission.C2D_MESSAGE
```

Permissions from Merged manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PROFILE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
    android:maxSdkVersion="18" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.****.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
```

From where is the READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission or why was it added?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any app that declares the WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission is implicitly granted `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission too.

[**See Android Official Docs.**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)

Comment: But the WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE  is set for maxSdkVersion 18. shouldn't it be used for the READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE?

Comment: @Ovi it dose not matter.

Comment: @Ovi if my post helps you little please vote up and tick mark.

Comment: Well I just uploaded new build to Google Play with <uses-permission        android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"        android:maxSdkVersion="18"/> and it fixed the problem. Thanks :)